# Is there any way to automate Window Server 2012/16 EC2 instance log backup directly to AWS S3

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, logging, server, backup

Like I already mentioned above, I am looking for a way to automate log backup for Windows Server to AWS S3.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will point you how to ask better, and get solution you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. You can write a batch script which uses aws cli to push your logs to s3. You can schedule a task which will execute this script. You also have to attach IAM role with s3 permissions to your windows EC2.
2. You can also stream this logs to cloudwatch using cloudwatch agent. Then you can stream this logs directly to s3. ex. [Using CloudWatch Logs Subscription Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html)

Comment: Thanks Shreyash. The first option that you mentioned seems to be interesting. Do you also use such a script for pushing logs to S3? If yes, can you please share that with me?